# Convergence related to a negative drift random walk

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, random-walk

Let $S_n$ be random walk with negative drift, i.e. $EX < 0$. ($S_n = X_1 + \dots + X_n$, $S_0 = 0$). Consequently, $S_n \to - \infty$ a.s. My question is whether this implies that $$ E \left (\frac{1}{\sum_{k=0}^{n} e^{S_k}} \right) \geq c > 0$$
for some $c$ holds. It seems reasonable that this holds, because $e^{S_k}$ should be exponentially decreasing. Can this be proven rigorously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an easy way to do it:

Let $E X = -\gamma < 0$;  I'm gonna assume that $|X| \leq 1$, but this works even without this assumption.  By Azuma's inequality, we have $$P(S_n \geq -\gamma \cdot n/2) \leq \exp\left( -\frac{\gamma^2 n}{8}\right)\,.$$

Thus there is some $M$ so that $$\sum_{n \geq M} P(S_n \geq -\gamma \cdot n/2) < 1\,.$$

Let $A_M$ denote the event that $ \{S_n \leq - \gamma \cdot n/2 \text{ for all }n \geq M\}$.  Then the above shows that $P(A_M) > 0$.  But on the event $A_M$, the expectation you are interested in is bounded below.

Comment: Great proof! Thank you very much.

Comment: When again thinking about this proof, I was wondering why you are using $\gamma$ at all. Couldn't we just do: By Azuma's inequality, we have $$ P (S_n \geq n) \leq \exp (-n/2) $$ and thus, for some $M$ $$ \sum_{n \geq M} P(S_n \geq n) < 1.$$ And the rest follows the same? So, we would have shown that for any supermartingale the expectation I am interested in is bounded from below. Is that correct?

Comment: $S_n$ is not a martingale, but $S_n + \gamma n$ is and so your application of Azuma's inequality is not correct.

Comment: Oh, ok. I looked the inequality up on Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azuma%27s_inequality) and it said supermartingale in parenthesis. I just googled again and it seems that a similar (but I don't think same) inequality holds for supermartingales. So it seems that one should not trust Wikipedia after all. Thanks again.

Comment: Ah, sorry, you're correct (and Wikipedia is correct!) that application of Azuma's inequality is correct.  But the issue is that your bound doesn't give a lower bound on expectation.  Try to complete the details of my answer and do the same with your comment and you'll see the issue.

Comment: Oh, you're also right. I would only attain $\exp(n)$ in the sum which is no proper lower bound at all. Thanks!